# Fire after function is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys this is the situation

```
function makeIt()
{
  //code
  createSomething()
}

function createSomething(){
 //code
  request.execute(function(resp) {
  function writeSomething(){
    //code
  }
   createSomething()
   goback()
 }
}
```

I want to execute the goback after `writesomething` is done.
The problem is that the `writesomething` function can be done in 2 sec or in 10 sec(depends on the file). I use for now a setTimeout just to be sure.
But how can I let goback exucute when writesomething is done ?

EDIT:

```
function writeToSheet(){
//this is a part of the function (deleted some information)
                params 

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.open('PUT', 'https://something.com');
            xhr.setRequestHeader(some things);
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See update at the bottom, now that you've included the `writeToSheet` definition.

---

If `writeSomething` is an *asynchronous* process, it will provide a way for you to know when it's done — it'll accept a callback, return a promise, etc. Pass `goback` as that callback (or as the `then` callback on the promise, etc.).

Example - **if** `writeSomething` accepts a callback:

```
writeSomething(other, arguments, here, goback);
// This is the callback ---------------^^^^^^
```

or

```
writeSomething(other, arguments, here, function() {
    goback();
});
```

...depending on whether you want `goback` to receive whatever arguments `writeSomething` passes its callback.

Example - **if** `writeSomething` returns a promise:

```
writeSomething(other, arguments, here).then(goback);
```

or

```
writeSomething(other, arguments, here).then(function() {
    goback();
});
```

...again depending on whether you want `goback` to receive the value passed to the `then` callback.

---

If `writeSomething` is a *synchronous* process that may take 2-10 seconds, just call `goback()` after calling `writeSomething`. Even if `writeSomething` takes 10 seconds, if it's truly synchronous, `goback` won't be called until it's done.

Example (just for completeness :-) ):

```
writeSomething(other, arguments, here);
goback();
```

---

**Update**: Your `writeToSheet` function starts an asynchronous process, so we want to edit it to either accept a callback or return a promise.

Accepting a callback:

```
function writeToSheet(callback){
//                    ^------------------------------------ ***
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {                // ***
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {                      // ***
            callback(xhr.status === 200);                // ***
        }                                                // ***
    };
    xhr.open('PUT', 'https://something.com');
    xhr.setRequestHeader(some things);
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
}
```

`writeToSheet` will call the callback with `true` if it was successful, `false` if not.

Then:

```
writeToSheet(goback);
```

or

```
writeToSheet(function(flag) {
    // Maybe use the flag here, or not, depends on what you want
    goback();
});
```

...if you don't want `goback` to receive the flag.

Returning a promise:

```
function writeToSheet(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {           // ***
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {                // ***
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {                      // ***
                if (xhr.status === 200) {                    // ***
                    resolve();                               // ***
                } else {                                     // ***
                    reject();                                // ***
                }                                            // ***
            }                                                // ***
        };
        xhr.open('PUT', 'https://something.com');
        xhr.setRequestHeader(some things);
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
    });
}
```

then:

```
writeToSheet().then(goback).catch(function() {
    // It failed
});
```

...which will only call `goback` on success and call the other function on failure, or

```
writeToSheet().then(goback, goback);
```

...which will call `goback` regardless.

Comment: Why do I get an error : callback is not an function ?

Comment: @Mralwayswrong: With the above, you won't. Be sure that you're passing in a function as the argument corresponding to the `callback` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

pass your callback function as a parameter

```
function writeSomething(callback) {
    ...
    callback();
}

function myCallbackFunction() {
    alert('hi!');
}

writeSomething(myCallbackFunction);
```

Comment: Code dumps are not useful answers.

Comment: I tried this got the error: callback is not an function